# scrapy How to insert one item with three column

Tags: python, scrapy

[how to insert i have three column in my flightDetails item but the only inserting is the first column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNIVg.png)

```
  items = DemoProjectItem()

      flightInfo = response.xpath("//div[@class='schedule-table-wrapper']/ul/li")
     
      for info in flightInfo:   
           #flightTime
           flightTime     = info.css('div.flight-time strong').css('::text').extract()

           #details

           flightDetails     = info.css('div.flight-details').css('::text').extract()
           #flightTerminal
           flightTerminal = info.css('div.flight-status span.terminal').css('::text').extract()
           
           
           items['flightDetails']   = flightDetails
           items['flightTerminal']  = flightTerminal
           items['flightTime']      = flightTime
           
           yield items
```

pipeline

```
def store_db(self, item):
        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO website_urls (flightDetails, flightTerminal, flightTime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(
              (item['flightDetails'][0]),
              (item['flightTerminal'][0]),
              (item['flightTime'][0])
          ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: Hello, the query you wrote is correct, but what is the error you're getting?

Comment: yes its correct   this is my json output https://ibb.co/Smk5Czp

Comment: and this is the database output  https://ibb.co/9VFzpqy

Comment: What error are you getting? What type of database are you using? What is the result you are after? Please provide this info for us to be abe to help you.

Comment: this is my flightDetails output
{"flightDetails": ["5J626", " Cebu Pacific\n              ", "Dumaguete (DGT)"]

and the first column is inserted in database "5J626"